# Giving Specified Data a Larger Value/Weight in a Model

Tags: natural-language-processing, classification, weights, text-classification

I'm in the process of creating a model to classify an occupational code based on a job title & description. I have a large sample of labelled data to achieve this.

The government has a resource with every occupation code's job description and the respective duties of each occupation, I wanted to know if there was a way to give the Government's occupation data a higher weight in the model (since there is only one description for each occupation code), rather than relying on data that was labelled by an individual since it could lead to variations/inconsistencies depending on the individual who was labelling it.

My apologies if using the term "weights" is incorrect to describe what I'm trying to achieve. If so, let me know the correct terminology.

Just to clarify, I'm not talking about giving certain classes/labels a higher weight to correct a class imbalance. I'm trying to give the regulatory SOC occupation descriptions a higher value in the model.